# Вопросы с одинаковым заголовком

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

Движок запрещает создание вопросов с одинаковым заголовком. Мне кажется такое поведение неправильным, потому что:

**Практические** вопросы вполне могу иметь одинаковый заголовок и разную суть. Например [Поиск подстроки в строке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/424304/). Я так понимаю, автор не смог создать вопрос с таким заголовком, поэтому **специально** сделал орфографическую ошибку в заголовке.
При этом такой вопрос (помощь по конкретному коду), насколько я знаю, не запрещен, если оформлен должным образом.
**Итог:** Автор вопроса был спровоцирован на орфографическую ошибку в заголовке.

**Теоретические** вопросы тоже могут иметь одинаковый заголовок и при этом быть полезными.
Приведу абстрактный пример: **Асинхронная загрузка файла** (если не очень удачный конкретный пример, прошу придумать лучше).
Вопрос был создан к примеру с меткой **php**. Теперь человек желающий задать такой же вопрос про **python** не сможет его создать. В вопросе с меткой **php** естественно никто не будет приводить код на **python** и всех остальных языках программирования.
Единственный выход: вносить метку в заголовок вопроса.
Выдержка из справки:

> Не стоит искусственно вставлять метку в заголовок. Так как метки находятся прямо под вопросом и поисковые машины индексируют метки вместе с содержимым вашего вопроса, поверьте, другие смогут найти ваш вопрос по меткам, за которыми они следят или которые они ищут. Кроме того, метки появляются на странице с вопросом, поэтому другие будут учитывать их при ответе на ваш вопрос.

**Python: Асинхронная загрузка файла** выглядит весьма искусственно для заголовка вопроса.

---

**Предлагаю** разрешить создание вопросов с одинаковым заголовком.

Answer (score 3):

Если единственное уточнение, которое вы можете внести в заголовок, состоящий из двух-трёх общих слов — это метки с языком программирования, то с вопросом что-то не так.

Например, обсуждаемый вопрос *"Поиск подстроки в строке"* по-хорошему стоит назвать *"Поиск подстроки в строке с помощью preg_match"*, потому что это точнее описывает происходящее в вопросе. Заголовок "Асинхронная загрузка файла" точно так же может быть уточнён.

Также следует учесть, что, хотя формы *"[метка] заголовок", "метка. заголовок", "метка - заголовок", "заголовок - метка"* следует избегать, нет ничего преступного в форме *"заголовок в метке"* или *"метка по метке в метке"*, если метка — это действительно ключевая информация.

Автоматика приводит заголовок к форме *"метка - заголовок"*, если в тексте заголовка отсутствует метка. Если этот заголовок не слишком удачен, то можно добавить метку в заголовок, и движок корректно обработает этот случай.

Также автоматика добавляет только первую метку. Если ключевая информация содержится не в первой по популярности метке, её следует добавить.

Некоторые пользователи придерживаются мнения, что метка в заголовке в любой форме — это преступление. Я не согласен и считаю, что в отдельных случаях метка в заголовке делает его более осмысленным. Не надо превращать заголовок *"Ошибка при установке Visual Studio 2038 в Windows 13: 0xDEADC0DE"* в огрызок *"При установке в: 0xDEADC0DE"* только по той причине, что у вопроса есть метки [visual-studio-2038](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2038), [windows-13](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-13) и [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0). Я уж молчу про суровые и беспощадные вопросы с Arqade вроде "Как убить невинных котят?" или "Полезно ли есть трупы на завтрак?", которыми вечно забиты Hot Network Questions.

Comment: Поиск подстроки в строке с помощью preg_match — не очень хорошее название, это подпадает под [проблему XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (как это на русском-то?).

Comment: То есть вы за заголовки «Правильная асинхронная загрузка файлов в C#»? Дублирование меток в заголовке, чтобы удовлетворить фильтр?

Comment: @VladD Под XY — да, попадает. Да, вопрос не идеален. Но на такие вопросы надо же как-то отвечать. Просто надо включать объяснение, как делать правильно; выяснять, что на самом деле надо и т.п. Правильный заголовок к неправильному вопросу — это лучше, чем неправильный заголовок к неправильному вопросу. Если проблема XY возникла у одного юзера, она может возникнуть и у другого. Хороший заголовок поможет найти обсуждение.

Comment: Окей, а что делать с _правильными_ вопросами? «Правильная асинхронная загрузка файлов» + метка C#?

Comment: @VladD Вопрос языков программирования в заголовках я рассмотрел в первом абзаце. Вопрос "Асинхронная загрузка файлов в C#", на мой вкус, слишком общий. Возможно, нужны какие-то дополнения.

Comment: Эээ, это какая-то уловка-22. «Асинхронная загрузка файлов при помощи `BackgroundWorker`» — это XY problem. А «Асинхронная загрузка файлов» — слишком общий?

Comment: @VladD Почему обязательно "с помощью"? Есть "... с прогресс-баром", "... нескольких файлов параллельно", "... с поддержкой отмены", "Обработка исключений при ..." и т. п.

Comment: А если мне не нужен прогресс-бар, несколько файлов и отмена? Тогда слишком общий? Или надо задавать два вопроса: с прогресс-баром и без?

Comment: @VladD Тогда можно добавить "... чтобы избежать блокировки GUI", "... чтобы увеличить производительность", "... в консольном приложении" и т. п.

Comment: Асинхронный же. Неблокировка GUI — это лишь одно из применений асинхронности. И консольное приложение или нет — вопрос для модели (а загрузкой файла занимается модель) неинтересный. Давайте предположим, что вопрос задаёт квалифицированный программист, и он не пишет «чтобы не писало что эксепшн», «штоб окошко можно было двигать» и тому подобное.

Comment: Да, заставлять менять заголовок вопроса до тех пор, пока система не согласится принять его --  очередная дурь. / Или это такой способ отсева недостаточно настойчивых?

Comment: @VladD Квалифицированный программист умеет пользоваться гуглом, поэтому такой вопрос не задаст. :) Если только не решил расписать всё во всех деталях в каноничном ответе. Тогда можно назвать "Сравнение способов ..." или что-то в этом духе. Великий и могучий достаточно велик и могуч, чтобы не упираться в невозможность формулировки одной мысли разными словами. И проблемы возникают только со слишком общими вопросами, которых не должно быть много. В общем и целом, проблема не существует.

Comment: @Discord: Не-не-не, меня лично злят вопросы, из которых торчит низкая квалификация программиста. Вот если бы я захотел узнать, как асинхронно загрузить файл в Java, скажем, я бы так и спросил. Или вы ратуете за изгнание хороших вопросов отсюда? :) Потому что ваш комментарий звучит как «квалифицированные программисты тут не приветствуются».

Comment: @avp В *нормальных условиях* проблема *не должна возникать*. В редких случаях она может возникать, да. Но редкие случаи можно разобрать и вручную. / Вот **зачем** добавлено это ограничение — вопрос интересный. Скорее всего, это как-то связано с SEO. То есть за счёт страданий программистов, задающих слишком общие вопросы, увеличивается качество результатов в поисковике. Как по мне, рационально.

Comment: @VladD Не надо обманывать, вы бы не задали этот вопрос. Вы бы загуглили и получили десятки ответов. На большинство подобных общих вопросов ответы уже даны.

Comment: @Discord: Гугл пошлёт меня сюда в любом случае. :) И да, десятки ответов во многом неправильные или устарели, и моей квалификации в Java не хватит, чтобы оценить их. Живой, квалифицированный ответ от человека, которого я знаю, гораздо ценнее. // Вопрос я бы не задал лишь потому, что постеснялся бы признаться в незнании простых вещей.

Comment: Не могу не заметить в очередной раз, что если все вопрошающие будут качественно пользоваться гуглом (и думать), то большинство отвечающих (да и сам сайт) станут просто лишними.

Comment: @avp: польза сайта в том, чтобы сделать ровно *один* запрос и получить конкретный ответ, а не 25 запросов на *каждого* вопрошающего, чтобы по сусекам собрать ответ.