# Имеет ли смысл убирать слово-метку из заголовка вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, правки

Очень часто заголовки вопросов звучат примерно так:

```
как в <имярек> сделать то?
<имярек>: как сделать вот так?
не работает эдак. <имярек>
```

где `<имярек>` — одна из присвоенных вопросу меток (`php`, `mysql`, `android` и т. д. и т. п.).

Имеет ли смысл (при редактировании вопроса) убирать `<имярек>` из заголовка, формулируя его «менее тавтологично»?

Ведь необходимое ключевое слово уже есть — в виде метки.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Похожая проблема уже поднималась при обсуждении вопроса "[Вопросы с одинаковым заголовком](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc)".

В большинстве случаев метки из заголовка следует удалять, но нужно следить, чтобы не страдал смысл. Здесь я несколько расхожусь во мнении с консенсусом на МСЕ, потому что предпочитаю оставлять метки чаще, чем рекомендуется.

Для начала рассмотрим случаи, когда метки однозначно надо удалять. Это тогда, когда в заголовке самая популярная метка, и она не является частью предложения. Автоматика приводит заголовок к форме *"метка - заголовок"*, если в тексте заголовка отсутствует самая популярная метка. В этом случае вручную добавленная метка совершенно избыточна. Если этот заголовок не слишком удачен, то можно добавить метку в заголовок, и движок корректно обработает этот случай.

Если метка редкая и не самая популярная в списке меток вопроса, если метка часть предложения, если без метки вопрос теряется смысл — метку следует оставить. Хотя формы *"[метка] заголовок", "метка. заголовок", "метка - заголовок", "заголовок - метка"* следует избегать, нет ничего преступного в форме *"заголовок в метке"* или *"метка по метке в метке"*, если метка — это действительно ключевая информация.

Некоторые пользователи придерживаются мнения, что метка в заголовке в любой форме — это преступление. Я не согласен и считаю, что в отдельных случаях метка в заголовке делает его более осмысленным. Не надо превращать заголовок *"Ошибка при установке Visual Studio 2038 в Windows 13: 0xDEADC0DE"* в огрызок *"При установке в: 0xDEADC0DE"* только по той причине, что у вопроса есть метки [visual-studio-2038](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2038), [windows-13](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-13) и [ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0). Я уж молчу про суровые и беспощадные вопросы с Arqade вроде "Как убить невинных котят?" или "Полезно ли есть трупы на завтрак?", которыми вечно забиты Hot Network Questions.

Comment: Отлично, у вас подробнее написано. Поддержу этот вариант.

Comment: Не так давно был спор по поводу заголовка [этого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/432233/Как-распарсить-нетривиальный-xml-на-питоне). Я по-прежнему считаю, что слова _на питоне_ там излишни. Во-первых, потому что по метке вполне понятно на каком языке программирования должна быть сделана задача за автора. Во-вторых, я понимаю, что название языка в русском закрепилось как _Питон_, а не _Пайтон_ (на вопрос _"как распарсить XML на Яве?"_ я бы отправил людей выяснять это в самой Индонезии), но допустимые границы отклонения должны быть. Ладно быть хоть _на Питоне_ написали бы...

Comment: Так вот я это к чему: не знаю насчет поисковых систем (в комментариях была речь про то, что не все поисковые системы одинаково реагируют на `Python` и `Питон`) и насчет того, до какой степени можно издеваться над названием `Python`, но впадаю ли я в крайности?

Comment: @Regent С точки зрения СЕО на странице должны присутствовать оба написания слова. :) Это, кстати, создаёт определённые проблемы, потому что из синонимов меток http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/synonyms на странице отображается только один. То есть запихивание русскоязычного написания в заголовок (или хотя бы в тело) поможет найти информацию тем, кто ищет по русскому названию (не знаю, насколько такие программисты распространены). Чисто с эстетической точки зрения "на питоне" мне не очень нравится, да и движок этот случай не обрабатывает нормально: получается "python - Как ... на питоне".

Comment: @Regent: Если в целях CEO добавлять ключевики из словарного запаса школоты, то школота и придет по запросам...

Comment: @NickVolynkin а это хорошо или плохо? :)

Comment: @Discord с эстетической точки зрения _"на питоне"_, равно как и _"python - ... на питоне"_, - страшные вещи. А есть ли уверенность в том, что в плане SEO (особенно учитывая, что SO и так неплохо заточен в плане SEO) оба названия в заголовке лучше? Программистов, увлекающихся в поиске питонами, анакондами и т.д., не встречал, но охотно верю в их существование.

Comment: @Regent: с моей точки зрения - плохо. Это усиливает [проблему с низким качеством вопросов](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/616/181472). Мы же не торговцы на рынке, чтобы любой ценой завлекать пользователей. И возможности наши ограничены. Считаю, что лучше меньше пользователей, но хороших, чем больше за счет бездумной школоты.

Comment: @Regent: Впрочем, тут тоже нужно с грязью ребенка не выплеснуть. Возможно, сначала нужно набрать количество, а потом оно перейдет в качество. Но я все-таки считаю, что нужно бороться сразу за качество - а количество вырастет как закономерный результат. И если сразу понижать планку ради количества пользователей, то потом поднять ее будет тяжело.

Comment: @Regent Оба названия в *заголовке* — не лучше, особенно если заголовок длинный, потому что заголовок будет урезан на странице результатов поиска. А вот есть ли польза от упоминания синонима *где-то вообще на странице* — это могут сказать только сеошники SE, потому что нужно смотреть, по каким ключевым словам на сайт приходят посетители.

Comment: @Regent: 1. Нужно использовать те заголовки, которые реальные люди используют. Если люди используют "парсить" на практике, то не важно, есть ли это слово в официальном словаре 2. Тяжесть доказательства на тех, кто изменяет заголовок: `python != питон`, поэтому не нужно заголовок менять. 3. В ответе или комментарии можно упомянуть о корректной терминологии, но вопрос изменять не следует

Comment: @jfs Люди разные бывают. Кто-то вообще не в состоянии сформулировать поисковый запрос. Кто-то не может составить его четко и лаконично из-за мешанины мыслей в голове и/или недостатка словарного запаса. Учитывая, что культура речи падает с каждым годом, может, стоит тогда оставлять заголовки "как есть"? Это я к чему: либо заголовки делать "правильно", либо так, как будут искать люди, которые не сильны в запросах.

Comment: @Regent: верно, если "либо" заменить на "и".

Comment: @jfs: это взаимоисключающие опции. Если писать "Как прочитать распарсить разобрать XML файл с угловыми скобочками на питоне петоне python", то это СЕО-оптимизированно, но ничуть не правильно. Пусть учатся писать нормальные запросы. Кто не научился - профнепригоден, вон из профессии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Это не сео-оптимизировано, это сео-загажено. Так "оптимизируют" только нубы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin:  *"и"* в моём комментарии означает, что  **РАЗНЫЕ** люди/вопросы могут использовать разную терминологию (какой идиот будет писать: *"Как прочитать распарсить разобрать XML файл с угловыми скобочками на питоне петоне python"*). И не следует чужие вопросы редактировать, чтобы "более правильную терминологию" использовать для этого есть ответы, комментарии.

Answer (score 4):

ИМХО категорически против удаления меток. Если вводишь вопрос то тебе выползает портянка "как поменять переменную". Одна тема из C#, другая PHP, а тебе нужен Python. И понятно что на 3-4 уже будет лень просматривать, а был ли такой вопрос? Вопросы становятся безликими

Comment: Тут поисковик надо доработать, чтобы метки включал в результаты. Пишешь "php как отсортировать массив" и получаешь результат "Как отсортировать массив" (вопрос с меткой php)

Answer (score 3):

Я считаю, что вопросы можно разделить на общие и частные.
Есть вопрос "Как поделить число нацело?".

Общая сторона этого вопроса это - "Как происходит деление числа нацело в различных языках программирования?".

Частные случаи - "Как поделить число нацело в javascript?" или "Как поделить число нацело в с++?". В данном случае способы разные.

Возникает следующая проблема:
Если пользователь задает вопрос "Как поделить число нацело?" и добавляет метку "javascript", то другой пользователь больше не сможет задать вопрос - "Как поделить число нацело?" и добавить метку "c++", так как заголовок уникален и вопрос с таким заголовком уже существует, но имеет метку "javascript".

Я считаю, что нужно более рационально относится к решению об удалении названия метки из вопроса и впервую очередь смотреть на общую и частные стороны редактируемого вопроса.

Так же возможным решением проблемы было бы - сделать проверку уникальности по сочетанию заголовка и меток.

Приводились примеры, что если метка очень популярна, то её стоит удалить из вопроса. В данном случае этот алгоритм для создания(редактирвоания) вопроса ошибочен, так как обе метки достаточно популярны. Это опровергает теорию о том, что нужно решать оставлять ли название метки в вопросе исходя из её популярности.