# Стоит ли отклонять правки, которые улучшают лишь часть недостатков?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

Коллеги, помогите разобраться как правильнее поступать в следующем моменте.

В очереди проверок "предлагаемые правки" есть два ревьюера, которые смотрят на некоторую правку.

Оба видят, что правка в чём-то улучшает вопрос/ответ. Первый ревьюер на этом основании считает, что правку нужно принять.

Второй ревьюер замечает, что в вопросе/ответе есть ещё недостатки и на этом основании считает, что правку нужно отклонить-и-править: вернуться к исходной версии текста и внести все возможные правки.

Причём, именно через отклонить-и-править, не давая +2 репутации участнику, который не заметил/сомневался/не имел времени на внесение всех правок. Хотя альтернатива очевидна: можно было бы нажать принять-и-улучшить или просто принять, а потом довнести правки (уже в обход очереди проверок, т.к. репутация для ревью достаточна для редактирования)

Скажите, как рекомендуется поступать в такой ситуации?

Аргументация за то, чтобы отклонить-и-править высказывалась следующая:

- следует приучать проверяющих делать сразу все правки.
- этому конкретному участнику, вносящему правки неоднократно указывалось на неполноту правок

Аргументация за то, чтобы принять высказывалась следующая:

- предлагающий правку может не видеть всех возможных ошибок в вопросе, сомневаться в целесообразности части из них, не иметь времени на полное исправление -- и не стоит демотивировать стремление улучшать сайт, предлагая правки

Какой из этих вариантов вам кажется наиболее правильным? Возможно, вы видите ещё более хороший вариант? Если так - предложите его в своём ответе.

---

Для тех, кому важен контекст вопроса.

Тема возникла из текущей ситуации в очереди правок. Некоторый участник достаточно много внёс правок заголовков вопросов (убирал из заголовков метки).

Соответственно, один из проверяющих считает, что эти правки нужно принять все (основание: [тема на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/213987)); другой проверяющий принимает только те правки, которые улучшают все недостатки вопроса.

И ещё момент. Корректно ли вообще заниматься подобным внесением сразу большого числа правок в очередь проверок? Зачастую многие участники для набора репутации заходят в очередь проверок, забивают её своими правками, а после того, как за проверки перестают давать репутацию - исчезают. (А потом приходят другие и цикл повторяется). Возможно, этот вопрос также уже обсуждался?

То есть как кажется, что ключевое в проблеме - подобное отклонение применяется ревьюером только в случае, когда уже не раз было рекомендовано участнику вносить сразу все возможные правки.

Comment: Кстати, не то, чтоб в VK много юзеров было, но там тоже все за принятие правки в опросе отметились: https://vk.com/stackoverflow?w=wall-33558403_237

Answer (score 12):

Я или контекста не понимаю, или он недостаточно полно описан. Зачем отклонят правку, если она полезна, даже при условии, что эта самая правка лишь частично вопрос улучшает? о_О

Каждый вносит свою лепту как может. Поэтому, лично я в таких случаях всегда выбираю **принять** или **принять-и-улучшить**.

> Корректно ли вообще заниматься подобным внесением сразу большого числа
>   правок в очередь проверок?

Когда я этим ещё занимался, то бывало, что я чистил конкретные метки, попутно вырезая из заголовков. Да, немного засоряет главную, но результат того стоит.

> Зачастую многие участники для набора репутации заходят в очередь
>   проверок, забивают её своими правками, а после того, как за проверки
>   перестают давать репутацию - исчезают. (А потом приходят другие и цикл
>   повторяется). Возможно, этот вопрос также уже обсуждался?

Вот это интересный вопрос. В каком-то треде это точно уже обсуждали. Я в принципе не особо одобряю такие правки ради репы, но если они не несут негативных последствий, то почему, собственно, нет.

> То есть как кажется, что ключевое в проблеме - подобное отклонение
>   применяется ревьюером только в случае, когда уже не раз было
>   рекомендовано участнику вносить сразу все возможные правки.

А можете ткнуть, где было такое обсуждение? У каждого разный бэкграунд. Да я, банально, мог не заметить, что ещё можно улучшить или думаю, что ничего улучшать больше не нужно. Почему из-за этого нужно отклонять правку? Нужно её дополнить или, по крайней мере, принять.

Comment: Как я могу ткнуть, где было такое обсуждение? Это было вне чата - вероятно, как обычно бывает в таких случаях - под любым вопросом обсудили правку, потом удалили. (Я по крайней мере всегда когда такие замечания по очереди проверок прочитывают - удаляю свои тексты как оффтопик) Поэтому - да, для меня это не аргумент: никто не знает, кто из ревьюеров достанется в тройке, обсуждения прошедшие мимо общественный мест "нищитовы". Даже создание чата ревьюеров не поможет особо: всегда есть шанс, что свежий ревьюер не читает чат. (Многие не читают чат)

Answer (score 7):

Да, бывает иногда объем изначальных правок настолько мал или бесполезен (и/или вопрос сам по себе настолько плох), что их можно и отклонить. Но, в остальных случаях, лучше их принять, т.к. даже неполное улучшение, лучше, чем никакое.

---

> Второй ревьюер замечает, что в вопросе/ответе есть ещё недостатки и на этом основании считает, что правку нужно отклонить-и-править.
>   ...
>   Скажите, как рекомендуется поступать в такой ситуации?

Как следует поступить кому?

> Аргументация за то, чтобы отклонить-и-править высказывалась следующая:
>
> - следует приучать проверяющих делать сразу все правки.
> - этому конкретному участнику, вносящему правки неоднократно указывалось на неполноту правок

За исключением явно плохих косметических правок (когда улучшение и/или сам вопрос настолько минимально, что не стоит поднятия вопроса в топ, или, даже, негативно), это неконструктивная позиция. Что значит "*все*". Идеал, как известно, недостижим. Тогда вообще можно все правки зарубать со словами, что они не приводят вопрос/ответ к совершенству.

> Аргументация за то, чтобы принять высказывалась следующая:
>
> - предлагающий правку может не видеть всех возможных ошибок в вопросе, сомневаться в целесообразности части из них, не иметь времени на полное исправление -- и не стоит демотивировать стремление улучшать сайт, предлагая правки

Плюсую.

> И ещё момент. Корректно ли вообще заниматься подобным внесением сразу большого числа правок в очередь проверок?

Спорный вопрос. С одной стороны это раздражает, с другой - приводит базу знаний в порядок. Пришлось побывать с обоих сторон этих баррикад. Консенсус, вероятно в том, чтобы делать все в меру. Штук 20 правок за раз достаточно.

Стоит также помнить о том, что тот кто сидит на сайте SO и смотрит на топ вопросов (и раздражается правками) - не совсем целевая аудитория SO. Основной массе посетителей интересны их конкретные вопросы найденные через поисковики или по похожим вопросам. Отвечающим скорее интересна лента новых вопросов и отслеживаемые метки. Мониторинг всего топа интересен скорее тем, кому заняться нечем ;-) (на Мете несколько иначе, т.к. там отслеживание топа - это во многом социальная жизнь)

> Зачастую многие участники для набора репутации заходят в очередь проверок, забивают её своими правками, а после того, как за проверки перестают давать репутацию - исчезают. (А потом приходят другие и цикл повторяется). Возможно, этот вопрос также уже обсуждался?

Пускай. Не важно какие у них мотивы, если они делают полезную работу.

Answer (score 6):

В общем случае правки, устраняющие недостатки сообщений, стоит принимать. Но есть один нюанс. Если всё сообщение в целом треш, угар и содомия (читай как "не соответствует приемлемому для ruSO контенту чуть более, чем полностью"), а участник предлагает правку, которая, ну, скажем, добавляет пару недостающих запятых, то подобную правку я бы не стал одобрять. Это значит, что участник не понимает ещё, какого рода контент ценен для сайта и сообщества в целом.

Я рекомендую ревьюверам в первую очередь ранжировать проблемы сообщения и устранять наиболее значимые из них. Если, например, вопрос явно вне тематики сайта, а предлагается в нём исправить опечатки, то пользы от этой правки не будет, ибо вопрос подлежит закрытию как офтопичный. Хотя будучи оптимистом можно рассмотреть и пользу от этой ситуации: правка поднимет вопрос в списке, его увидят больше людей и ... закроют быстрее. Но это сильно притянутая за уши польза.

Например, недавно я наблюдал предложенную правку, где при наличии в вопросе текста полностью на украинском языке было предложено изменить заголовок с фразы "Помогите решить" на "Помочь с решением арифметической задачи". И всё. Весь остальной текст остался не тронут. Вопрос получил свои минусы и был закрыт, а скоро и вовсе будет удалён с сайта. Туда ему и дорога.

Здесь, кстати, стоит заметить, что переводить текст вопроса за его автора [не рекомендуется](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8107/176217). Но так как эта была самая главная его проблема, устранять более мелкие не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

Правки, которые не содержат ничего, кроме удаления метки из заголовка, принимать не нужно. Я считаю, такие правки нужно рассматривать как несущественные - не по количеству символов, а по общей полезности. Дублирование меток в заголовке, в сущности, не проблема. Если же правка в целом полезна, хоть и не исправляет все возможные проблемы с сообщением, конечно, нужно ее принимать.

> Корректно ли вообще заниматься подобным внесением сразу большого числа правок в очередь проверок?

На сайте много сообщений, требующих правки, во всех смыслах (в том числе, сообщения с полностью разрушенным форматированием), так что да, предлагать правки в больших количествах можно и нужно. В движке уже заложены ограничения на количество ожидающих правок и от одного пользователя и в целом по сайту, так что проблем с перегрузкой очереди не должно быть.

Comment: А вот [бывали и перегрузки](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345125/3240681), правда на enSO.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, [текущий консенсус](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/607/213987) на ruso и mce подразумевает, что удаление метки из заголовка - существенная правка.

Comment: @AK ну не знаю, там автор ответа какой-то забаненный ... можно ли ему доверять?!

Comment: @älёxölüt только таким и нужно доверять (¬‿¬ )